# Blue card interruption - Germany - Pregnancy

Tags: germany, blue-card

I was hired for a position in Germany starting from the 1st of December, 2021 and I will be moving there from Turkey.  I will apply for a Blue card. I am married. My husband is in a job search right now.  My question is: What happens if I get pregnant while working within the first year of employment? Let's say I got pregnant after 6 months of work, and 9 months later I have to take maternal leave.  Will maternity leave put my blue card at risk?

Comment: I hope that you have found a good answer and you are doing well now.
We have now the same situation you had,and we are lost and don't know what to do.
Can you please help us and give me some advice and information. Best,